Is there a name for the arc $\mathbb{S}^1 / (x \sim360 - x)$
I was playing with some ideas in a vague way and I have encountered this structure that arises from taking the space of angles $\mathbb{S}^1$ and quotienting it by the relation $(x, 360-x)$ (here $360$ refers to degrees and can be $2\pi$ if you want to work in radians).
This is a very similar looking structure to the projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^1$ which arises from $\mathbb{S}^1/(x \rightarrow x + 180) $ however its worth noting that $360-x$ has a fixed point $x=0$ and $x+180$ does NOT have any fixed points so this is definitely a different structure.
My friend and I have been calling this "the arc" but I figured to ask if anyone knows what this object is and what sort of algebraic structures can be naturally associated with it? It's not even clear if it is a group at all but on very small slices it seems to behave like $\mathbb{S}^1$.

As John Hughes says, this is "the closed unit interval" or "a closed line segment". Some comments - you can picture what's happening as taking a circle and squashing it from two sides to make it flat (gluing the points from one side to the other). For algebraic structure - it cannot be made into a topological group, because its automorphism group doesn't act transitively on it. Addition mod 1 is not an algebraically or topologically very nice operation on the closed interval!

Thanks for commenting! Can this have some kind of type that is not "topological group" but more specific than "arbitrary group on geometric set". I claim that this arc is a "nice" or "natural" structure yet I do not have a name for what the "type" of this group + underlying set should be.

What is the nice/natural structure you're talking about? The operation of addition of angles modulo $360$ doesn't descend naturally to this quotient. But even considering addition mod $1$ on $[0, 1]$, there is no identity element and it's pretty discontinuous. Just as a topological space, it is quite nice - it's a compact one-dimensional manifold-with-boundary.

I can explain what I mean by metaphor. Consider the image $\tan^{-1}(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}\cup \infty$. There is a "homomorphism" here via $\tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x+y}{1-xy} \right)   = \tan^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(y)$ so the interval $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ with the group structure addition modulo $\pi$ should be viewed as some kind of non-discontinuous thing. It's kind of like a copy of $S^1$ (if we identify $-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$  except there are half as many angles here). It also seems to have a connection with $Gr(1,2)$ in the sense that...

...every value on that interval is related to a line passing through the origin and $\tan^{-1}$ of the slope of the line produces an angle on the line. And so for some reason I feel like it is its own distinct thing, but I cannot articulate any property of this space that differentiates it from the standard representation of $S^1$. (Yet we also know the standard representations of S^1 and Gr(1,V) are not the same so these both CANNOT be identifies with our arctangent image space!).  I am concerned I am overcomplicating the matter, and that this is just all really $S^1$ with unusual behavior.

@IzaakvanDongen that tangent angle sum formula would be the "nice" or "natural" structure inherited from $\mathbb{R} \cup {\infty}$ to this space that I am talking about.

Initially I had naively said things like $\tan^{-1}$ is a map from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$ but that obviously is NOT the right way to view it. Yes it produces angles as output, but it produces angles in the range from $-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}$ yet that slice of angles should be viewed as a continuous structure of its OWN. with its own addition formula. I think it's also wrong to say that $\tan^{-1} : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow Gr(1,2)$ so I guess I'm just dumping word soup attempting to find the right $X$ to confidently say $\tan^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$

Your space also has 180 as a fixed point. And there's a lovely map from the closed unit interval to your space, namely
$$
x \mapsto [180*x]
$$
where brackets denote "the equivalence class of".
Because your space is diffeomorphic to this well-known manifold-with-boundary (the unit interval), a topologist would probably just call it "the unit interval".

I am curious, since the unit interval lacks a nice group structure outside of addition mod 1 (which makes it just a copy of $S^1$). Then similarly is this "arc" with an addition that wraps around simply just a slightly more complicated version of $S^1$?
